# PdfiumViewer Pdfium Exception - VS2017 Created Project must be .Net 4.0 and then upgrade to any higher versions

Tags: c#, pdf, rendering, pdf-viewer, pdfium

VS2017 ver 15.9.3

NuGet Packages
PdfiumViewer version="2.13.0.0"

PdfiumViewer.Native.x86_64.v8-xfa version="2018.4.8.256"

## Test Scenario - Load PDF file with PdfiumViewer

1. Create Project1:  Target Framework = .Net Framework 4.   Program runs successfully.
2. Change Project1 to any higher Framework - 4.5, 4.5, 4.6 ... 4.72    Program runs successfully

**3. Create Project2:  Target Framework = .Net Framework 4.7.2 or any other FW 4.5, 4.5, 4.6  ( ** NOT FW 4 ).

Error Message: $exception   {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}    System.BadImageFormatException**

4. Change Project2 to FW = 4.   Program runs successfully.
5. Change Project2 to any higher Framework - 4.5, 4.5, 4.6 ... 4.72    Program runs successfully

## Code

Error Message: $exception   {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}    System.BadImageFormatException

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string pdf = @"D:\PDF\TestFile.pdf";

     try
     {
        var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdf);   // *** Exception  ***
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
  }
```

==============

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add both the **x86** and **x64** folders containing ***pdfium.dll*** to the Debug/Release directories, that should be the way. In case you don't know where to find them, run the *PdfiumViewer.Demo* project from [PdfiumViewer Github](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer), you will find them inside the **bin** folder.

Comment: Do you intend this to be a clarification question or an actual attempt to answer the question? In the first case please have a look here (though you probably are aware)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead In the second case please rephrase into a more assertive answer, otherwise this risks being mistaken for the first case and closed for being not an answer.